# What is the correct way to write a file path for an image on an Android phone if you're developing an HTML5 Webpage?

Tags: android, html, mobile-website

[My HTML file, index.html, and the picture 1603139547165.jpg are in the same file path or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrX7Y.png)

I tried this in my HTML code `<img src ="1603139547165.jpg" alt ="hello world">`

Only a small unloaded image shows with HELLO WORLD next to it. Is there a special way to reference files that are stored on an Android phone? The image is in my Internal Storage.

Comment: No. This should work.

Comment: If you wanna fetch file from Assets folder this might help you. src="file:///android_asset/img/38_JK_551_11_01_2020.jpg"

Comment: I tried what you said, Mr Moradiya. It didn't work. Thank you very much, still. Blackapps, I think you are right. This must be a bug or something like it. I remember trying the same referencing style with a phone before. What I can't remember now is whether it was an Android or not.